# Send SMS programmatically on scheduled time

Tags: android

Is there any way to send SMS programmatically on scheduled time ? Without checking current time in every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Android Timer class' [schedule method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) to schedule the sms to be sent using something like the following in the run() method of the scheduled [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html#run%28%29):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

For a formatted date string, to get the `when` argument of the `schedule()` function, use the `SimpleDateFormat` class' [`parse() method`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29). If your date string is "12/31/2013-12:12", then you can get the date object using:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm");
Date when = sdf.parse(yourDateString, 0);
```

Other options for the SimpleDateFormat [are here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I have dates in String in that kind of format:"12/31/2013-12:12" so I thin it's very difficult and not a good way to calculate seconds for TimerTask